# Highcharts: Plot the errorbars behind the datapoints

Tags: highcharts

Is there a possibility to plot the errorbars in highcharts behind the actual lines/datapoints?

I am usually plotting the data and the errorbars with a for loop, therefore it would be convenient to set an attribute for the errorbars.

```
series: [
            {% for key in dataset %}
            {
                name: '{{key}}',
                data : {{ dataset[key].data}}
            },
            {
                name: ' error',
                type: 'errorbar',
                data : {{ dataset[key].error}}
            },
            {% endfor %}
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be controlled by the `zIndex`, like this:

```
series: [
  {% for key in dataset %}
  {
    name: '{{key}}',
    data : {{ dataset[key].data}},
    zIndex: 2
  },
  {
    name: ' error',
    type: 'errorbar',
    data : {{ dataset[key].error}},
    zIndex: 1
  },
  {% endfor %}
]
```

**API on series.zIndex:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.errorbar.zIndex

> Define the visual z index of the series.
>
> Defaults to undefined.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vrdmdzmz/1/